# how to get plain text of json data when calling stack api to instead of 'application/json'?

Tags: json, api, stack

How to get the response of stack api in plain text of json data , not response application/json , because the first way of respnose can be handled directly by progamme

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answers. Because api of stackoverflow return "application/json" content-type, so 
my python script cannot read it as plain text.  In fact, "application/json" is a file, and I use methods get the file encoding , that is gzip. So , I can use "gzip" module of python to read it now. Yeah!

Here is my sample script of calling api of "http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/stats":

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import urllib
import simplejson as json
import gzip
import cStringIO
def run():
    url = 'http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/stats'
    c = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
    s = cStringIO.StringIO(c)
    gzfile = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=s, mode='rb')
    content = gzfile.read()
    data = json.loads(content)
    print type(data)
    print data
run()
```